# I have installed StyleCop in MS VS Web Developer Express and cannot edit the settings

Tags: stylecop, visual-web-developer-2010

I am looking for the settings file to manually change the settings - but cannot find it.

I followed these directions to install: http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setting%20Up%20StyleCop%20MSBuild%20Integration

(with one exception, I placed the StyleCop.Targets file within my project folder)

StyleCop runs correctly, but I want to change the settings - where do I go to find the settings folder?  I read that it looks in the directory that StyleCop.Targets is located, then moves up a directory until it reaches the root of the drive searching for the file - but I cannot find it.

An alternative to finding it would be finding a sample StyleCop settings file online somewhere so I can download it and place it in my directory and point to that settings file.  Does anyone know of such a file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am now thinking StyleCop uses 'default' settings if it does not find a settings file anywhere.  Does anyone have a sample settings file I can have so I can customize it and place it where I need it to go?

Answer (score 3):

you will not see UI integration of StyleCop since the VS Express edition does not support integration of add-ins and packages like StyleCop.

If you are using Express, you could still run StyleCop, but this will require using either MSBuild integration or a pre- or post- build event.

[Refer this link to configure StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Running%20StyleCop%20in%20VS2005%20or%20VS%20Express)

Comment: As I am using Visual Studio Express for this project I do not think this is an option.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In regards to your update - I have integrated StyleCop using the above method - but the option is not there when I right click on a project.  Everything appears to be running because when I debug I get a list of warnings with all of StyleCop's messages.  Is it possible to get the level of integration you speak of while using VS Express?